# A generating function related to the Delannoy numbers

Tags: generating-functions, recurrences

What is the generating function of $f_{m,n}$?

$ f_{m,n} = \begin{cases} 0   , & \text{if $m<0 $ or $ n<0$ }; \\
 f_{n,m} ,  & \text{ if $n<m$};  \\
  1, & \text{ if $0=m$ and $ n\in\{0,1\} $};  \\
    f_{0 ,n-1}+  f_{1,n-1}, & \text{ if $0=m$ and $ n>1 $};  \\ f_{m-1 ,n}+   f_{m ,n-1}+  f_{m-1,n-1}, & \text{ if $0<m\in \{n,n-1\} $};  \\
      f_{m-1 ,n}+   f_{ m ,n-1}+  f_{m-1,n-1} +  f_{m+1,n-1},& \text{ if $0<m<n-1$}. 
\end{cases}
$

Comment: Will it yield taking partial derivatives in the two variables sequence to construct the generating function. Here is an example. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/686102/generating-function-for-recurrence-relation-in-2-variable

Comment: It might make sense to restrict to $0\le m\le n$, define boundary functions (for $n=0$, $m=n$, and $m=n-1$), and use the kernel method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following generating function:
$$F(x,y) := \sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{m=0}^n f_{m,n} x^n y^m$$
and its diagonal
$$D(z) := \sum_{n=0}^\infty f_{n,n} z^n.$$
Then the recurrence implies the following functional equation:
$$2(1-x-y-xy)F(x,y) - 2x\frac{F(x,y)-F(x,0)}y = 1 + (1-xy-2y)D(xy).$$
I'm not yet sure if it can be solved explicitly.

---

It's also worth to mention a couple of boundary properties for $F(x,y)$:
$$[y^1]\ F(x,y) = \left.\frac{F(x,y)-F(x,0)}y\right|_{y=0} = \frac{(1-x)F(x,0)-1}x$$
and
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_{n-1,n} z^n = \frac{(1-z)D(z)-1}2.$$

---

**ADDED.** Introducing another generating function:
$$G(x,y) := F(x,\frac{y}{x}) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{m=0}^n f_{m,n} x^{n-m} y^m$$
we get a self-contained functional equation:
$$2(y-xy-y^2-xy^2-x) G(x,xy) = y + (y-2y^2-xy^2) G(0,xy) – 2x G(x,0).$$